# Code converted to function not working

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to make some `vlookups` and paste the values on another sheet. I generated the original code using the Macro recorder, then tried to modify it to make it a function that requires only to indicate the page with the data to look up and the range on sheet 3 to paste the results.
Original code:

```
Sub Look1()
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-1],Sheet4!C:C[3],2,FALSE)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B13531")
Range("B2:B13531").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-2],Sheet4!C[-1]:C[2],3,FALSE)"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C13531")
Range("C2:C13531").Select
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-3],Sheet4!C[-2]:C[1],4,FALSE)"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D13531")
Range("D2:D13531").Select
Columns("B:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Columns("D:F").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Function attempt (This is the one not working).

Function:

```
Sub Look(Page As Variant, Rango As String)
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-1],Page!C:C[3],2,FALSE)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B13531")
Range("B2:B13531").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-2],Page!C[-1]:C[2],3,FALSE)"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C13531")
Range("C2:C13531").Select
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-3],Page!C[-2]:C[1],4,FALSE)"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D13531")
Range("D2:D13531").Select
Columns("B:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Columns(Rango).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

And I call the function like this:

```
Look Sheet5, "G:I"
```

When I try to run it, I get a pop up window for file browse that says as title "Update Value:Page", apparently I'm doing something wrong replacing sheet and the range, but I cant figure out what it is, my function doesn't work. I'm going to do this code for 35 page sheets, So I would rather do it calling a function.

Comment: What exactly are you passing into the `Page` argument?

Comment: I call the fuction like this: Look Sheet5, "G:I"   ....The page argument, its the sheet in which is located the table array im using for the vlookup. But Im not doing it right apparently.

Comment: This is going to fill your target sheet with a bunch of cells that have the vlookup formulas in them. Is that what you want to do or did you actually want to code vlookups to get the values?

Comment: My programs performs 3 vlookups in columns B:D in sheet 2, the table arrays of the 3 vlookups are located at sheet4, and the Values of the vlookups are pasted in Sheet3 D:F, then I want to repeat the same thing but now use a table array on sheet 5 and paste the values of the vlookups on Sheet3 but on columns G:I this time (so I dont overwrite the previous values). Then repeat the process till sheet 34. What i attempted to do, was to make a function in which I just feed the name of the sheet im looking the table array in, and the range of columns in sheet 3 Im pasting my values into, didnt work

Comment: With `Page` being a variant, there's a risk that using `Sheet5` as the parameter value will end up referring to a built-in shortcut name for the worksheet which was called "Sheet5" when it was created. This would pass a Worksheet object into the function and cause an error. Better to declare `Page As String` and pass the worksheet name in double-quotes "Sheet5"

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your VLOOKUP, first parameter needs to be a a cell,  not a column `C[-1]`

try  `RC[-1]` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're inserting the formula "=VLOOKUP(C[-1],Page!C:C[3],2,FALSE)", which a string and will be inserted directly into the cell.  If you want to insert the correct sheet name and range, you need to concatenate them in.  Like this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(C[-1]," & Page & "!" & Range & ", 2, FALSE)"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the error: Expected array, didn't work for me :(

Comment: This fixes the specific error that caused your error message.  There are other issues as well.  As Steven Martin said, "C[-1]" refers to a column, but you need to be looking up a single cell.  For example, RC[-1].  That should solve the array issue.